# Create XCode 4 lib out of an project

Tags: xcode, compilation, static-libraries

I have a project with several classes. Now I want two libraries, one exactly for one class and one containing two classes.
Therefore i added two new products "libA.a" and "libB.a"
At the class-m-files i chose as targets "libA.a" or "libB.a"

It tells me, it puts the libs in a folder. But this folder is empty.

Can anyone tell me a step by step explanation, how this is possible.
(I also tried to crate a new product for static libraries, only added this one class and it compiles, but I can nowhere find this lib-File).

So the basic question: Where can I find a Tutorial, how to create a lib (only for IPhone, not for a simulator or universal or so...). URL, ... any help is appreciated.
Or can anyone tell me my missing step(s), do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was sooo simple ...
When starting the compilation, it is possible to choose the target next to the play-stop-buttons. The toolbar looks like this.

PLAY  STOP   TARGET   DEVIVE

Click on the Target, chhose LibA, press "Play" (=Compile) and it works. Same for LibB.